# Reading Records into RPGLE Loop?

Tags: loops, rpgle

I'm stuck on a problem.I know for the loop to execute i need to read the records within the loop but I can't figure out how to  do that..here's what I have of this part of the code. I can't figure out what to do

```
    //Initial Subroutine
    Begsr Initial;
    Write Headings;
    Read WUINPAY;
      Holdvar=pinst#
      DoU %Eof;
       If Holdvar <>0;
       Endif;
      Enddo;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the READ within the loop.

The most usual way to code a read loop is

```
read ...
dow not %eof;
   do stuff
   read ...
enddo;
```